# SetWindowLongPtr with GWLP_WNDPROC does not work with fullscreen applications since 1803 (C++)

Tags: c++, windows

Since the 1803 update, SetWindowLongPtr seems to have changed in some way. The function returns no error codes, and a valid value. Applies to both x64 and x86 applications. Only happens in fullscreen applications (games). In windowed applications, the same (valid) return values are returned and the hook works as expected.

My code has remained the same for quite a long time, and only presented this problem after upgrading to 1803.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), as well as reading all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons you might get negative votes on your question. Lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, previously I was only hooking the first window belonging to the process id with this code:

```
    static HWND hwndTarget = NULL;
    auto CaptureWindow = [](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL
    {
        DWORD lpdwProcessId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &lpdwProcessId);
        if (lpdwProcessId == lParam)
        {
            hwndTarget = hwnd;
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    };
    EnumWindows(CaptureWindow, static_cast<LPARAM>(pid));

    if (hwndTarget == NULL)
    {
        LOG("Unable to find target window handle");
        return false;
    }

    gWndProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(SetWindowLongPtr(hwndTarget, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)WindowProc));
```

However the following code fixed it:

```
std::vector<HWND> hwnds;

    GetAllWindowsFromProcessID(GetCurrentProcessId(), hwnds);

    if (hwnds.size() == 0)
        return false;

    for (auto& h : hwnds)
    {
        WNDPROC oldProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(GetWindowLongPtr(h, GWLP_WNDPROC));

        if (oldProc == 0)
            continue;

        gWndProcs[h] = oldProc;

        gWndProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(SetWindowLongPtr(h, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)WindowProc));
    }

    return true;
```

Comment: Note, you should be using [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) instead of `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`, see [Safer subclassing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883).

Comment: Updated Old New Thing link for 2022 - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883